# how is the geometrical representation is done here in this link

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

here in this picture how the vector represented i.e. $v_1+2v_2$ , help me please[image]

Comment: It's a 40 minute video. Be more specific.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector addition is most easily visualized by placing the tail of one arrow at the head of the other.  The two arrows thus form two sides of a triangle, the third of which is the vector sum.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_addition#Addition_and_subtraction) or [this](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-1/Vector-Addition) for more details.